# What creates new instances recursively?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

In the MainModelView I have the following:

```
    // constructor
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        SelectedSystemItem = _systems.Where(x => x.Key == Properties.Settings.Default.SASE).First();
    }

    private KeyValuePair<int, string> _selectedSystemItem;
    public KeyValuePair<int, string> SelectedSystemItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedSystemItem;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _selectedSystemItem, value);
            var locator = (ViewModelLocator)Application.Current.Resources["Locator"];
            var vm = locator.LocationsPageVM;
            vm.UpdateCells();
        }
    }
```

somewhere in ViewModelLocator:

```
    ...
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LocationsPageViewModel>();
    ...
    public LocationsPageViewModel LocationsPageVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<LocationsPageViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

`LocationsPageViewModel` is empty class derived from `ViewModelBase`.

LocationPage.xaml

`DataContext="{Binding LocationsPageVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"` in page tag.

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Generator.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Generator.ViewModel"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             mc:Ignorable="d ignore">

    <Application.Resources>
        <!--Global View Model Locator-->
        <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                             d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Problem is that I am getting stack overflow, because it appears every time I am getting new MainViewModel instance(because after var vm = locator.LocationsPageVM debugger is jumping to MainViewModel's constructor). Locator object is also new every time during this dead loop. So I am looking forward to understand what makes this dead loop.

Comment: It is clearly tagged

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this line causes re-instantiation of ViewModelLocator

```
var locator = (ViewModelLocator)Application.Current.Resources["Locator"];
var vm = locator.LocationsPageVM;
vm.UpdateCells();
```

Try removing them. Also notice that mvvm light puts these line to MainWindow.xaml

```
DataContext={StaticResource Locator, Binding Main}
```